# tableSorter pager not updating after search

Tags: tablesorter, pager

I have tablesorter and pager working together and had no problems so far.
Only thing that I can't manage to do correctly is update the pager after a search.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Country</td>                        
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Al</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BAl</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CAl</td>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DAl</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>Australia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>EAl</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I initialize the sorter and the pager to display only 2 rows per page, but after searching for 99 year old person still pager will show 1/3 and not 1/1 which is the correct!

Pager still works, is that visual total page count that is wrong!

Any tips?

Comment: Are you using the latest version (this was an issue in older versions)?

Comment: Thanks Mottie, that did the trick!
Guess I will have to keep an eye on the updates... :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help or not, but I have it working on mine.

Super important note, all the examples the Official Sorter page has does not use a ID of the table, it just says any table tag.  (add the # to the reference)

```
$("#caseInfoTable").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}); 
$("#caseInfoTable").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false});
```

[1]
In the jquery.tablesorter.pager.js file I added these two lines at line 110...

```
c.pagerPositionSet = false;
fixPosition(table);
```

Those 2 go right before the line

```
updatePageDisplay(table);
```

[1] https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-problem-with-tablesorter-pager-plugin-there-should-be-an-option-to-turn-off-absolute-positioning-of-pager-container/